# Can I create automated tests for an IBM Mainframe application in Java

Tags: java, automated-tests, mainframe, cics

Is there a way I can create an automated regression test suite in Java for IBM Mainframe applications? Preferably open source. I found some frameworks and tools, but the problem is most are either not in Java or are very expensive to license.

Some I found are:

- [Jagacy Jameleon plug in](http://jameleon.sourceforge.net/jagacy-plugin/index.html)
- [IBM Rational Functional Tester](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/functional)
- [MF-Test](http://www.mf-test.com/)
- [CA-Verify](http://www.ca.com/us/devcenter/ca-verify-for-cics.aspx)
- [HostExplorer](http://connectivity.opentext.com/products/terminal-emulation.aspx)

Comment: I think this is too wide a question as it stands. What kind of application? What protocols are you trying to interface to? How much does the test have to muck with application configuration to set up the test conditions? If you can't narrow this, then all we'll be able to say is "yes, there is a way."

Comment: Honestly, I was told to just research this. So, I don't know a whole lot about the applications. I know they are very old, over 30 years. I would say there would be a fair amount of configuration to set up test conditions. Mostly the interface for these systems is through a terminal emulator of sorts. One of the applications runs on CICS. I would be looking for a way to send commands to the mainframe. Thanks

Comment: zOS runs Java, so there's probably a way to write JUnit test cases for at least some parts of the applications.  The System/370 R8 JRE could invoke CICS and read/write record-oriented files from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing applications in CICS it should be possible to run the JUnit framework in the WebSphere Liberty Profile available since CICS TS V5.1 (see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc/topics/liberty_overview.html?cp=SSGMCP_5.2.0%2F5-3-2). The test cases could use the JCICS  API including LINK to call applications written in COBOL and other supported languages. Of course there are also a variety of production offerings too including Rational Integration Tester (Green Hat).

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

There are certainlý 3270 terminal emulators written in Java. Java can support CORBA and other older/business protocols. "If it happens, it must be possible." So the answer to your question as asked is "almost certainly yes".

Can't advise on tools without knowing *exactly* what you're doing. And tool recommendations are usually ruled out of bounds here as too opinion-based.

Define the problem better, and that will help you research what's available.